# SQLite's sqlite3_exec and callback as class member

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

I'm trying to do it

```
class Foo
{
 static int ReadSelfFromBase(void *userarg, int argc, char **argv, char **ColName){...}

public:
 void Bar(sqlite3* db)
 {
 ...
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "select * from test", &ReadSelfFromBase, this, &zErrMsg);
 ...
 }
}

int main()
{
Foo test;
...
test.Bar(db);
}
```

But callback doesn't call. If a do this

```
int main()
{
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "select * from test", Foo::ReadSelfFromBase, NULL, &zErrMsg);
}
```

it all well. Does anybody know how solve this problem

PS Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ReadSelfFromBase is a static function, Foo::ReadSelfFromBase should work the same in the Bar method as it does in main.

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use `Foo::ReadSelfFromBase` any where you want, you know, it's static.